# upload file and text in same view grails

Tags: forms, grails, file-upload, submit, form-submit

I am having trouble getting a text input and a file upload from the user both of which I save to the database. I have two forms in the .gsp page one is for the text inputs and another is for the file upload. I am able to either save the file or get the text input, but I can not do both. When I place my submit button inside the  tags for the textfield inputs it saves those, and when I place it in the  tag it saves the file, but how can i get it do both on the click of a single submit button. I don't want to have multiple submit buttons. The two forms call upon the same method to save the data.

The example on this site is what I am looking for but it doesn't say how the information gets sent with the click of a single submit button:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails06099/index.html

Comment: You Unaccepted my answer to Accept your own? Even though I gave you the entire solution and all you did was basically restate what I had said about the difference between the form tags. IMHO that is very bad form and will make people stop helping you.

Comment: yo relax, I thought I could select multiple answers, if it makes you feel better I will select your answer it doesn't matter to me

Comment: It's about acknowledging the people who help you - yo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `<g:uploadForm...>` tag does is set the form enctype to `multipart/form-data`.  To upload standard text inputs and files I usually just do the following:

```
//GSP
<g:form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="update">
   <input type="text" name="myTextField" id="myTextField" />    
   <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
   <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
</g:form> //closing tag fixed
```

Then what you do in your controller depends on how you are saving the uploaded file.  If you are saving it into a `byte [] myFile` it will automatically bind if the field name is set correctly, so you don't have to do anything  - it just works.

```
//controller
myInstance.properties = params  //binds text as well as upload files
```

If you are saving it to the file system you could do something like this (straight from the [manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles)):

```
//Controller
def f = request.getFile('myFile')
if (f.empty) {
    flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
    render(view: 'uploadForm')
    return
}
f.transferTo(new File('/some/local/dir/myfile.txt'))
response.sendError(200, 'Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

The submit button submits the contents of the form it's contained within. The answer to your question is either: a) have 1 form and 1 submit button, or b) have 2 of each.

Comment: then how is he doing it here with just one submit button:               http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails06099/index.html

Comment: Your link is, unfortunately, just showing snippets (hence the <!-- SNIP comments), but it looks like the upload markup is inside 1 `<g:form>` tag.

Comment: yeah that's the problem, i can do each separately but doing it together is what they didn't show and what I need. I tried putting the uploadForm tag inside the regular form tag but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

it also works if instead of having the `<g:form>` you just make it an `<g:uploadForm>` tag